# Opacity gradient in drag and drop

Tags: html, css, drag-and-drop, gradient, opacity

I'm trying make a drag and drop component, but when dragging an opacity gradient is automatically applied.

I performed several tests and I noticed that when the component less than 300px approximately, only an opacity is inserted, not perfect, but it'll do. However, when it exceeds this size (300px), a gradient is applied in addition opacity, making the user experience bad.

how to resolve this?

I'm trying remove opacity gradient with CSS and others.

I expected remove opacity gradient on drag.

**Sorry, i'm using google translate

```js
const columns = document.querySelectorAll(".column");

document.addEventListener("dragstart", (e) => {
  e.target.classList.add("dragging");
});

document.addEventListener("dragend", (e) => {
  e.target.classList.remove("dragging");
});

columns.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
    const dragging = document.querySelector(".dragging");
    const applyAfter = getNewPosition(item, e.clientY);

    if (applyAfter) {
      applyAfter.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", dragging);
    } else {
      item.prepend(dragging);
    }
  });
});

function getNewPosition(column, posY) {
  const cards = column.querySelectorAll(".item:not(.dragging)");
  let result;

  for (let refer_card of cards) {
    const box = refer_card.getBoundingClientRect();
    const boxCenterY = box.y + box.height / 2;

    if (posY >= boxCenterY) result = refer_card;
  }

  return result;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'poppins';
  font-size: 30px;
}

.kanban {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 400px;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  min-width: 500px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.item {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Kanban</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="kanban">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="item" draggable="true">Card 01</div>
      <div class="item" draggable="true">Card 02</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="item" draggable="true">Card 03</div>
      <div class="item" draggable="true">Card 04</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="item" draggable="true">Card 05</div>
      <div class="item" draggable="true">Card 06</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi:) It would help if you provide the JS as well.

Comment: sorry i was still editing